# Q: Python - multiprocessing.Queue() only return one set data

Tags: python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

I'm working on django. My project trying to compare one doc to others.
This example of my data:

original document:

```
doc_original.txt
```

test document:

```
doc1.txt
doc2.txt
doc3.txt
```

I save content of `doc_original.txt` on variable called `txt`. Then, to access content on `doc1.txt, doc2.txt, doc3.txt` i use this code:

```
for i in testdocument:
    for pat in i.chunks():
        pat = prep_text(pat)
```

The multiprocessing.Queue() start in this section:

```
 for testfilename in testdocument:
        for pat in testfilename.chunks():
            pat = prep_text(pat)

            processes = []
            queue = Queue()
            processes.append(Process(
                      target=sim, 
                      args=(txt, pat, txtfilename, testfilename, queue,)))

for pr in processes:
       pr.start()

for pr in processes:
       pr.join()

print (queue.get())
```

this the `sim` method implementation

```
def sim(txt, pat, txtname, patname, q):
        txtlen = len(txt)
        intersect = 0
        similarity = 0

        intersect = full_search(txt, pat)

        similarity = 1 - ((txtlen - intersect) / txtlen)

        q.put({"sim(%s, %s) = %f" %(txtname, patname, similarity)})
```

I expect that the output should be like this:

```
sim(doc_original.txt, doc1.txt) = percentage
sim(doc_original.txt, doc2.txt) = percentage
sim(doc_original.txt, doc3.txt) = percentage
```

but it's only return:

```
set(['sim(doc_original.txt, doc3.txt) = percentage'])
```

Can someone please help to fix my mistake? Because i'm new in this multiprocessing technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `queue` multiple times, at every iteration of the for loop. Try moving the declaration of queue to outside the loop.

```
queue = Queue()
for testfilename in testdocument:
        for pat in testfilename.chunks():
            pat = prep_text(pat)

            processes = []
            #queue = Queue()
            processes.append(Process(
                      target=sim, 
                      args=(txt, pat, txtfilename, testfilename, queue,)))
```

To loop through the `queue`, you need iterated over the queue until it's empty.

```
while not queue.empty():
    print (queue.get())
```

Comment: Edited to also answer your new query.

Answer (score 0):

**[Update]**
i move the list `processes` and `queue`

```
 processes = []
 queue = Queue()
 for testfilename in testdocument:
        for pat in testfilename.chunks():
            pat = prep_text(pat)

            processes.append(Process(
                      target=sim, 
                      args=(txt, pat, txtfilename, testfilename, queue,)))

for pr in processes:
       pr.start()

for pr in processes:
       pr.join()
```

Then, i try to print the results like this

```
print (queue.get())
print (queue.get())
print (queue.get())
```

i write it three times because i have 3 output to display, and the result looks good.
Now, i updated my question to "can print the queue object through the loop?"